# Bxslider hiding text

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I'm using http://bxslider.com/ and I wonder is it possible to hide text faster than an image?
I have a background image which has less width on bottom, and I want to change the image normally, but hide text 30px from left and right side faster.

Maybe something like:

Wrapper is 500px, and hidden (overflow: hidden) with jquery 30px from left and right
Or maybe it possible to add some kind of mask?

Comment: Please post the relevant code you currently have implemented and have issues with. In **addition** to the relevant code a fiddle on jsFiddle.net is always handy, if possible.

Comment: I don't have any idea how to do it? By css or jquery. Don't have any clue how to get closerto solution

Comment: Have a look at the jquery documentation in the effects category: http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/ also have a look at jQuery UI under effect methods:  http://jqueryui.com/docs/Effects/Methods Ones you have some code you are having issues with feel free to post it and someone will surely help you out.